# Translating JavaScript oop code to Lua

Tags: javascript, oop, lua

I'm trying to translate a bunch of code from JavaScript to Lua. I'm stuck on the next bit though. I don't understand the Lua object oriented syntax. Can someone show me what the correct syntax is? Thanks!

```
//=======================================================
//=======================================================
//=======================================================
// The TMaze object
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Ctor
function TMaze(nHigh, nWide) {
    this.high = nHigh;
    this.wide = nWide;
    this.ary = TMazeArray(nHigh, nWide);

    this.totRooms = gnHigh * gnWide;  // less (short) bottom line
    this.curRoomCnt = 0;  // rooms that have been visited/door opened

    this.GetCell = function(x,y) {return this.ary[y][x];}
    this.SetCell = function(x,y,value) {this.ary[y][x] = value;}

    this.HasCellBit = function(x,y,value) {return ((this.ary[y][x] & value) == value);}
    this.SetCellBit = function(x,y,value) {this.ary[y][x] |= value;}
    this.ClearCellBit = function(x,y,value) {this.ary[y][x] &= ~value;}
    this.ToggleCellBit = function(x,y,value) {this.ary[y][x] ^= value;}

    this.IsEmptyCellAt = IsEmptyCellAt;  // some member fns, defined below
    this.IsValidXY = IsValidXY;
    this.GetNewXY = GetNewXY;
}

//----------- TRUE if cell in that direction is empty and valid
//
function IsEmptyCellAt(x, y, dir) {
    var o = this.GetNewXY(x, y, dir);

    if (!this.IsValidXY(o.newX, o.newY))   return (false); 
    if (this.GetCell(o.newX, o.newY) != 0)  return (false);

    return true;  // yes, it's possible to move into that cell
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// return -1 if that would be an invalid move (off the board)
// true if X,Y is on the board
//
function IsValidXY(x, y) {
    if (y < 0) return (false);
    if (y > this.high-1) return (false);

    if (x < 0) return (false);
    if (x > this.wide-1) return (false);

//    if (y & 1) {  // on off Y, max X an maxY are 1 less
//        if (x > this.wide-2) return (false);
//        if (y > this.high-2) return (false);
//    }
    return true;  // possible to move into that direction
}

//------------------------------------------
// If I move in a direction, what are the new X,Y values?
// Return an object with newX and newY properties
//
function GetNewXY(x, y, dir) {
    var oRet = {"newX":-1, "newY":-1, "isValid":false};
    var newX = x;
    var newY = y;

    newX += ganDeltaX[dir];  // add the deltas
    newY += ganDeltaY[dir];

    if (this.IsValidXY(newX, newY)) {
        oRet.newX = newX;
        oRet.newY = newY;
        oRet.isValid = true;
    }
    return oRet;
}
```

You can ignore the bitwise operations since I already figured out how to translate that. I'm mostly concerned with the oop stuff.

[edit]

Here's what I have so far, but it crashes.

```
--=======================================================
--=======================================================
-- The TMaze object
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Ctor
TMaze =
{
    high = gnHigh,
    wide = gnWide,
    ary = TMazeArray(gnHigh, gnWide),
    totRooms = gnHigh * gnWide,         -- less (short) bottom line
    curRoomCnt = 0,                     -- rooms that have been visited/door opened
}
TMaze.GetCell = function(self,x,y) return self.ary[y][x] end
TMaze.SetCell = function(self,x,y,value) self.ary[y][x] = value end
TMaze.HasCellBit = function(self,x,y,value) return bit.band(self.ary[y][x], value) == value end
TMaze.SetCellBit = function(self,x,y,value) self.ary[y][x] = bit.bor(self.ary[y][x], value) end
TMaze.ClearCellBit = function(self,x,y,value) self.ary[y][x] = bit.band(self.ary[y][x], bit.bnot(value)) end
TMaze.ToggleCellBit = function(self,x,y,value) self.ary[y][x] = bit.bxor(self.ary[y][x], value) end

--=======================================================
------------- TRUE if cell in that direction is empty and valid
--
TMaze.IsEmptyCellAt = function(self, x, y, dir)
    local o = self.GetNewXY(self, x, y, dir)
    if (not self.IsValidXY(self, o.newX, o.newY)) then return 0 end
    if (self.GetCell(self, o.newX, o.newY) ~= 0) then return 0 end
    return 1  -- yes, it's possible to move into that cell
end

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- return -1 if that would be an invalid move (off the board)
-- true if X,Y is on the board
--
TMaze.IsValidXY = function(self, x, y)
    if (y < 1) then return 0 end
    if (y > self.high) then return 0 end

    if (x < 1) then return 0 end
    if (x > self.wide) then return 0 end

--  if (y & 1) then  -- on off Y, max X an maxY are 1 less
--      if (x > self.wide-2) then return 0 end
--      if (y > self.high-2) then return 0 end
--  end
    return 1  -- possible to move into that direction
end

--------------------------------------------
-- If I move in a direction, what are the new X,Y values?
-- Return an object with newX and newY properties
--
TMaze.GetNewXY =  function(self, x, y, dir)
    local oRet = {newX=-1, newY=-1, isValid=0}
    local newX = x
    local newY = y

    newX = newX + ganDeltaX[dir]  -- add the deltas
    newY = newY + ganDeltaY[dir]

    if (self.IsValidXY(self, newX, newY)) then
        oRet.newX = newX
        oRet.newY = newY
        oRet.isValid = 1
    end
    return oRet
end
```

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799078/how-can-one-implement-oo-in-lua

Comment: It helps a little. But as you can see (I updated my initial post) my problem is more complicated.

Comment: where and with what error message does it crash?

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
self.IsValidXY(self, newX, newY)
```

to

```
self:IsValidXY(newX, newY)
```

made it work for some reason.

Comment: They're actually the same thing. using ':' is just syntactic sugar and includes the 'self' argument automatically